# "ImportError: no module named *" when using systemd service to run python script

Tags: systemd, autostart

I'm trying to run a python script automatically at bootup by creating a systemd service with the following paremeters:

```
[Unit]
Description=python_autostart
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/my/python/script/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python main.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When i restart the systemd service script (sudo systemctl restart python_autostart), i get the following error:

```
python_autostart.service - python auto start service
  Loaded: loaded(/etc/systemd/system/python_autostart.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: failed(Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-07-18 08:36:28 WIB, 2s ago
  Process: 6710 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python main.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) 
   Main PID: 6710 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

<timestamp> user systemd[1]: Started python_autostart service.
<timestamp> user python[6710]: Traceback (most recent call last):
<timestamp> user python[6710]: File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
<timestamp> user python[6710]: import psutil
<timestamp> user python[6710]: ImportError: No module named psutil
<timestamp> user python[6710]: python_autostart.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
<timestamp> user python[6710]: python_autostart.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

When i execute the python main.py in my directory with root privilege, it's working fine, however when i use systemd service to run this python script, the above error occurs. I've already installed the python module psutil (otherwise i can't run manually)

Grateful for any advice / comments.

Thanks!